# How specify platform independent paths in java.security and policy files?

Tags: java, security

I want to ship a single security policy file to our customers - for both Linux and Windows. In the java.security file, I add a line to point to our file, but due to path differences I have to specify it differently for Windows and Linux

```
policy.url.3=file:/${our.home}/lib/OurSecurity.policy  # Windows
policy.url.3=file:${our.home}/lib/OurSecurity.policy   # Linux
```

That first "/" after the "file:" is needed on windows since the variable our.home is defined as "C:\foo".  I have the same problem in the policy file itself:

```
grant codeBase "file:/${our.home}/-"   // Windows
grant codeBase "file:${our.home}/-"    // Linux
```

I'm especially looking for a clever way to specify the codeBase in a platform independent way.  By the way, redefining our.home is not really an option, as it's needed in a FilePermission clause.

Comment: are you processing these properties in your own code somewhere?

Comment: These are standard files read directly by the JVM.

Comment: This is a reference to the file syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would accept the fact that I needed different files and generate the linux version from the windows version by having a script to remove the "/".

However if you really need to use the same file, you could swap one pain for another by just defining another environment variable to represent the "/" on windows and have it blank on linux.

```
# our.hack = "/" on windows
# our.hack = "" on linux
policy.url.3=file:${our.hack}${our.home}/lib/OurSecurity.policy
```

Perhaps our.hack is not the best name in a production environment, but you get the idea. The variable is not used for anything else, so should not interfere with the rest of the app.

Comment: Yeah, these are the only ideas I've had so far, too. I was hoping I'd missed something better.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use the same policy file?
JRE is different for Linux and for Windows so you should follow that and keep different versions for each installation.
IMO there is no issue of maintenance of having 2 files in *this* case.
Also I would suggest that you should focus your concern on the fact that a java update could delete your policy file.

Comment: The reason for wanting one file is for maintenance.  The file which follows a specific format, is *identical* for both environments except for that silly slash. It's too easy for someone in the future to make an update to one file and forget the other.  In case it's not clear, whether it's one file or two, they are shipped by us in our installable kit.

Comment: @DaveC:As already said IMO this is a case that you shouldn't care so much about maintainance (the worry here is the deletion of the file in an update).If you think you **must** deliver one file, I suggest you write some script that produces the file on each target environment taking into account the slashes instead of trying to figure out some "hack"